# Sending docusign contracts as another Salesforce user

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Our current plan for Docusign for Salesforce is that we would have the Admin Support for sales to send out contracts for sales, is there a way to have the email to send as if it is from the account/opportunity owner in salesforce? Happy for it to go to the account manager to then sign.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that through customization of your system or through the Apex Toolkit or an API call but the user would have to exist in Salesforce/DS - I would suggest the apex toolkit as it would be the easiest and more manageable solution.